# How to detemine if the ADS account password needs to be reset at first login

Tags: c#, active-directory

An ADS entry is created with  .ExpirePasswordNow() (requiring user to change the password on firstLogin).. But authentication fails if the .ExpiresPasswordNow() is set..
How could I get authenticator (Domain principal) to accept this as a valid account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ExpirePasswordNow, set the property [pwdLastSet] to 0.

```
usr.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = -1; // To turn on, set this value to 0.
usr.CommitChanges();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180915.aspx